# Is it possible to attain (near) light speed in space?

Tags: speed-of-light, vacuum, rocket-science

As there is no drag in space/vacuum, is it possible to actually send a probe with enough fuel to have it achieve the speed of light or a value very near to it? Since there are not many significant forces that can slow down the speed (also why planetary motion will still continue for billions of years, I suppose) I am assuming fuel is our only restriction.

Is that correct?

Comment: I suggest you employ the rocket equation to estimate how much fuel would be required. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation

Comment: There are alternatives to rockets that avoid Tsiolkovsky tyranny, but no matter how you reach a relativistic speed (i) you'll need to accelerate hard or over a long distance & (ii) what little matter exists in space will not only pose a danger, but cost you kinetic energy at a rate proportional to speed cubed. But there are proposals to address these issues.

Comment: There is drag in space from gas and tiny particles. It is a very small amount, but at relativistic speeds you run into a lot more of them a lot faster and they hit a lot harder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by user John Doty in the comments, we can use the relativistic version of the Tsiolkovsky Rocket eq.
$$\Delta v = c \tanh\big (\frac {v_\text{e}}{c} \ln \frac{m_0}{m_1} \big)$$

> As there is no drag in space/vacuum, is it possible to actually send a probe with enough fuel to have it achieve the speed of light or a value very near to it?

The goal here is to find the wet to dry mass ratio of the rocket $m_0/m_1$ needed for say $.99c$ so we can rearrange
$$\exp{\big(\frac{c}{v_e}\text{arctanh}\frac{\Delta v}{c}}\big) = \frac{m_0}{m_1}$$

and now we can plug in an exhaust velocity $v_e = 5$ km/s and our desired ratio of the speed of light to [find](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=exp+%28c%2F%285+km%2Fsecond%29*arctanh%28.99%29%29+) a whopping $$\frac{m_0}{m_1} = 10^{68917}$$ For a probe with the mass of [$1000$ kg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_2), this is a wet mass of $$m_0=  10^{68920} \text{ kg}$$
For comparison, the mass of the sun is only $10^{30} $kg.

Another consideration brought in the comments from DKNguyen is

> There is drag in space from gas and tiny particles. It is a very small amount, but at relativistic speeds you run into a lot more of them a lot faster and they hit a lot harder

And so in practice, there will be an effective drag which will cost you kinetic energy $ \propto v^3$ and is not considered in this calculation.

As an aside, we can use a [Hall-effect thruster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall-effect_thruster) that can get to a $v_e \approx c$ (from a comment by Gyro Gearloose) and find $$\frac{m_0}{m_1} = 14$$ which means that we still would need $14$ times the dry mass to get the rocket to $0.99c$.

Comment: Uhhh...Houston we have a problem! LOL! Perhaps, one could go with nuclear fuel??

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Orion_(nuclear_propulsion)

Comment: Please either ignore periods or put them inside the latex env. Having them float on the next line looks ridiculous.

Comment: @KyleKanos edited

Comment: Also, 50 km/s is an abnormally fast exhaust velocity. Typical NASA rockets (with solid boosters) have an exhaust velocity of like 5 km/s. I would think that the idealized rocket to get to relativistic speeds would probably be emitting closer to $c$ exhaust anyway

Comment: @KyleKanos edited to include these  2 changes.Thanks for feedback

Comment: @KyleKanos https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall-effect_thruster can get up to that exhaust velocity.

Comment: I am wondering, ... if there is drag, there is matter, of some kind, which could be used, by some future technology, as thrust material. It would be ionized, or get ionized quickly, so some kind of magnetic "valve"  would do the trick of catching it, let it flow *around* the space ship and put some more energy in it, thrusting it behind.

Comment: @GyroGearloose Pretty much, except instead of around, you pump it through the middle. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bussard_ramjet

Comment: @gs petty technical details ;-) . Once someone will put his mind up to doing it at all.

Comment: @GyroGearloose Through one of the links another user provided, I learnt that it's not possible for even a civilization of Kardashev type II to build a Bussard ramjet at the first place... so I'm assuming despite of being possible theoretically, this concept is still beyond our practical abilities.

Comment: @Mei what is that link? Anyway, it might not be possible to use the hydrogen collected as a source of energy, but as reaction mass.

Comment: @GyroGearloose this one; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bussard_ramjet

Comment: @Mei, thank you, I have followed the link and seen that statement, but I don't see what the Kardashev scale on how much energy a civilization can harvest has anything to do with a Bussard ramjet, You simply don't need all that energy to build one.